# How to hide under line color of the edittext when it not focused and have text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

This is what i want to achive:

[image]

There are two pair edittexts in the picture. The bottom edittexts is possible with the current edittext. But if the edittext loses focus and has text in it, how can I hide the underline? But if there is focus again, it should work like the current edittext.

Comment: add following lines to your xml.
 android:inputType="none"
 android:background="@null"
 android:focusable="false"